# how can i get a children part of a json by keyname and value in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, hashtable

I got a json like:

```
var jsonData = {
    "id": 0,
    "content": "abc",
    "children" : [{
        "id": 1,
        "content": "efg",
        "children" : []
        }
        {
        "id": 2,
        "content": "hij",
        "children" : []
        }
    ]}
```

I just wanna get a children part of a json by searching correct key and value.
Like

```
 if(id == 2)
```

then I can get `jsonData.children[1]`, and then I can do other things on this object I got.
It's like a more efficient way which like `indexOf()`

It reminds me of using Hashtable in Java and C#. Well javascript seems like have no hashtable.

So, is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: the question is not quite clear to me. You want search the root json by id, or any inner object by id. For example, if only the top most json, then if you search by 0, it should return the whole object. If you only want to search its children, then the search should return the first children. If you want search everything that has id 0, then it should return both

Comment: i just want to search the root json by id, which is unique , so that i can add new objectA to the object's(whose id is correct) children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion and a reducer:

```
function find(pred, coll) {
  return coll.reduce(function(acc, obj) {
    if (pred(obj)) {
      return obj
    } else if (obj.children.length) {
      return find(pred, obj.children)
    } else {
      return acc
    }
  },null)
}

find(function(o){return o.id===2}, [jsonData])
//^ {id: 2, content: 'hij', children: []}
```

If no object with that id is found then it will return `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter`:

```
var idToMatch = 2;
var matches = jsonData.children.filter(function (el) {
    return el.id === idToMatch;
});
```

**UPDATE: Added recursive case**

To expand this to the recursive case to at least provide an alternate approach to the much more elegant approach from the answer from @elclanrs above (which is the best answer here), but the below is added just for completeness.

```
var matches = [];
function findMatches(children, idToMatch) {
    if (children && Array.isArray(children)) {
        var newMatches = children.filter(function (el) {
            return (el.id === idToMatch);
        });
        Array.prototype.push.apply(matches, newMatches);
        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++)
            findMatches(children[i].children, idToMatch);
    }
}
findMatches(jsonData.children, 3);
console.log(matches);
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vafwg3kf/

Comment: will it work when the correct object is jsonData.children[i].children[j]...?

Comment: No, this is not recursive and won't get the children of nested children. I'd recommend elclanrs's answer for that to select the nested children recursively.

Comment: @Pencil_Case - I added the recursive case for completeness. I would still go with the answer from elclanrs above, but went ahead and completed this answer so at least it is complete and available should it help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript objects are by default Maps. For instance,

```
var child = {}
child[1] = {"id": 1, "content": "efg"}
child[2] = { "id": 2,"content": "hij"}
```

you could retrieve the value like

```
var value = child[1].content;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may be a way.
It is inspired by @Jason W , @Mr.Green and @elclanrs .

**I tried this, and it did work actually.**

However, there is still some questions confused me about why it could work like this, and i will post my question later. Please check it out if you can help me.

```
var dataMap = {};

function matchData (jsonObj) {
  dataMap[jsonObj.id] = jsonObj;

  if (jsonObj.children.length > 0) {
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonObj.children.length; i++) {
      dataMap[jsonObj.children[i].id] = jsonObj.children[i];

      if (jsonObj.children[i].children > 0) {
        matchData(jsonObj.children[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}

matchData(jsonData);
console.log(dataMap[2]); 
//you will get "{"id": 2,"content": "hij","children" :[]}
```